# Linq to Entity Framework returned value results in error if not debugged

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I’m trying to use Entity Framework 6.1.3 with code-first on a WPF application with a gridview to show some data. However, when I try to query the database part of the data is lost when I return the result.

I have the following model classes:

```
public class Categoria
{
    [Key]
    public Guid IDCategoria { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public bool Visible { get; set; }
    public virtual List<SubCategoria> SubCategorias { get; set; }
}

public class SubCategoria
{
    [Key]
    public Guid IDSubCategoria { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public Categoria IDCategoria { get; set; }
    public bool Visible { get; set; }
}
```

And the `dbContext`:

```
public class PresupuestoContext : DbContext 
{
    public DbSet<SubCategoria> SubCategorias { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Categoria> Categorias { get; set; }

    public PresupuestoContext() 
    {
        var ensureDLLIsCopied = System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.Instance;
    }
```

To query the data, I’m using the following function:

```
public static IEnumerable<Categoria> GetCategories()
{
    using (var db = new PresupuestoContext())
    {
        var query = (from b in db.Categorias
                    orderby b.Nombre
                    select b).ToList();
        return query;
    }
}
```

The result here is returned two times until it reaches the GUI on this code:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var resultado = Information.GetCategories();
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = resultado.ToList();
}
```

And the data is shown on the grid

[image: expected result]

However, it only works when I set a breakpoint on the `GetCategories()` method AND look at the objects

[image: observed debugger]

If I don’t do that, the `SubCategorias` list throws an error

[image]

Error:

> ((System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Categoria_DEF110A52595D71D72012731564BC6530201A7738FF55979B05BFABCE100FD94)new
>   System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView(resultado).Items[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1mlT.png)).SubCategorias
>
> error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection'

And I get the following result

[image]

How can I make it so I get the results correct without having to step into the debugger?

Any idea of why this happens?

Comment: when you LOOK at the objects, there is an additional db call to show you the actual results (Lazy Loading). Before that, the referenced objects are not queried and null, in which state they remain when you leave the context (which is in the outside of GetCategories()). Either utilize Lazy Loading within GetCategories by enumerating the results, or do all within one query (EF will create the Join) with Eager Loading, like @Sampath suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do it like this.

**Note :** Use Eager loading with `Include`.

```
using System.Data.Entity;

public static IEnumerable<Categoria> GetCategories()
{
    using (var db = new PresupuestoContext())
    {
        var query = (from b in db.Categorias
                    orderby b.Nombre
                    select b)
                    .Include(p => p.SubCategorias)
                    .ToList();

        return query;
    }
}
```